# Error: export 'default' (imported as 'Swal') was not found in 'sweetalert2' (module has no exports)

Tags: javascript, angular, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to include sweetalert2 in my Angular project, but it gives compile time error. The error

> /src/app/pages/signup/signup.component.ts:29:16-25 - Error: export
> 'default' (imported as 'Swal') was not found in 'sweetalert2' (module
> has no exports)

### step follow

1. install sweetalert2
2. import on component .ts file (import Swal from 'sweetalert2')
3. call by using `Swal.fire()`

> /src/app/pages/signup/signup.component.ts:29:16-25 - Error: export
> 'default' (imported as 'Swal') was not found in 'sweetalert2' (module
> has no exports)

anyone having solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. So you need to first make sure of that you are including the required css & js files in angular.json/angular-cli.json (depending upon your ng version)

```
  "styles": [
        "../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js",
      ],
```

2. then, in your component, you can import it like this

```
import swal from "sweetalert2";
```

3. And in your component you can use it like this

```
swal({
     type: 'success',
     title: 'your message',
     showConfirmButton: false,
     timer: 1500
   });
```

Comment: I already updated the angular.json file with css and js file,still getting same error

Comment: did you try importing and using swal like in the answer? I used sweet-alert2 in one of my projects, it worked like this

Comment: no i m using swal.fire().It shows complile time error ./src/app/pages/signup/signup.component.ts:29:16-25 - Error: export 'default' (imported as 'swal') was not found in 'sweetalert2' (module has no exports)

Comment: dont use swal.fire. Try using like swal only, as shown in the answer.

Comment: this.userService.addUser(this.user).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        swal({
          type: 'success',
          title: 'your message',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 1500
        });       
        console.log(data);
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(error);
        this.snack.open("Something went wrong !",'',{duration:1000});
      }
      )

Comment: Did it work like this?

Comment: it shows error this expression is not callable. Type 'typeof swal' has no call signatures.

Comment: did you import swal? try using swal.fire()..

Comment: yes first i installed sweetalert2,then add css and js in angular.json,then add import to ts component file,then when i m trying to call any method i get this error

Comment: can you create a plunker or anything? whats the version of swal you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error, problem was that I was exporting the component as:

```
const Component = () => { Swal.fire({ //configs... }) 

export default Component;
```

I deleted that last line and changed to:

```
export const Component = () => { Swal.fire({ //configs... })
```

And everything started to work again.